# Button on React does not change back its color (from green to gray) once it is clicked again. The problem shows up only on responsive

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a button with a gray checkmark image on it, once it is clicked it changes the state and shows the checkmark to green, if it is clicked again it changes the state again and goes back to gray. The functionality works as intended on different browsers with different dimensions, but not on any mobile device. On a mobile device, even on Chrome's responsive the button stays green after being clicked for a second time, but it goes gray if I click anywhere on the screen. Can someone please point out what the issue might be?

TodoItem.js

```
import "../Styles/TodoItem.css";

function TodoItem(props) {
  return (
    <li className="itemContainer">
      <button className="edit" onClick={props.onOpenEditionModal}></button>
      <button
        className={`check-mark ${props.completed && "check-mark-active"}`}
        onClick={props.onComplete}
      ></button>
      <p className="id">{props.id}.</p>
      <p className={`text ${props.completed && "text-completed"}`}>
        {props.text}
      </p>
      <button
        className="delete delete-active open-delete-modal"
        onClick={props.onOpenDeleteModal}
      ></button>
    </li>
  );
}

export { TodoItem };
```

TodoItem.css

```
.itemContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

li {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 8px solid #f58335;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 1.3em;
}

.id {
  color: #f58335;
  margin-top: 1.3em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.itemContainer .text-completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.itemContainer .edit {
  background: url("../Assets/edit-gray.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3em;
  right: 16em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemContainer .edit:hover {
  background: url("../Assets/edit.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemContainer .check-mark {
  background: url("../Assets/check-mark-gray.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  right: 7.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemContainer .check-mark:hover {
  background: url("../Assets/check-mark.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemContainer .check-mark-active {
  background: url("../Assets/check-mark.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}

.itemContainer .delete {
  background: url("../Assets/delete-gray.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
  right: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemContainer .delete:hover {
  background: url("../Assets/delete.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .itemContainer .edit,
  .itemContainer .edit:hover {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    top: 1.5em;
  }

  .itemContainer .check-mark,
  .itemContainer .check-mark:hover {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    top: 1em;
  }
  .itemContainer .check-mark-active {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
  }

  .itemContainer .delete,
  .itemContainer .delete:hover {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    top: 1.4em;
  }
}
```

TodoContext.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocalStorage } from "../Hooks/useLocalStorage";

const TodoContext = React.createContext();

function TodoProvider({ children }) {
  const {
    item: todos,
    saveItem: saveTodos,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useLocalStorage("TASKAPP_V1", []);
  const [openDeleteModal, setOpenDeleteModal] = React.useState(false);
  const [openCreationModal, setOpenCreationModal] = React.useState(false);
  const [openEditionModal, setOpenEditionModal] = React.useState(false);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState("");
  const [todoToDelete, setTodoToDelete] = React.useState(null);
  const [todoToEdit, setTodoToEdit] = React.useState(null);

  const completedTodos = todos.filter((todo) => !!todo.completed).length;
  const totalTodos = todos.length;

  const searchedTodos = todos.filter((todo) => {
    const todoText = todo.text.toLowerCase();
    const searchText = searchValue.toLowerCase();
    return todoText.includes(searchText);
  });

  const addTodo = (text) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.push({
      id: newTodos.length + 1,
      text,
      completed: false,
    });
    saveTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const editTodo = (id, newText) => {
    const newTodos = todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, text: newText } : todo
    );
    saveTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const completeTodo = (id) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    const todoIndex = newTodos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === id);
    newTodos[todoIndex].completed = !newTodos[todoIndex].completed;
    saveTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const updatedTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    const newTodos = updatedTodos.map((todo, index) => ({
      ...todo,
      id: index + 1,
    }));
    saveTodos(newTodos);
    setOpenDeleteModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider
      value={{
        loading,
        error,
        todos,
        openDeleteModal,
        setOpenDeleteModal,
        openCreationModal,
        setOpenCreationModal,
        openEditionModal,
        setOpenEditionModal,
        addTodo,
        editTodo,
        deleteTodo,
        todoToDelete,
        todoToEdit,
        setTodoToEdit,
        completedTodos,
        totalTodos,
        searchValue,
        setSearchValue,
        searchedTodos,
        completeTodo,
        setTodoToDelete,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { TodoContext, TodoProvider };
```

I have tried using a state (isActive, setIsActive) and a handler and the situation remains the same. I have also applied :active on the css but it did not fix the situation.

Comment: I have found the solution. In the css file I changed the hover to:

@media (hover: hover) {
  .itemContainer .check-mark:hover {
    background: url("../Assets/check-mark.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

Leaving this here in case it might help someone in the future!